# opengl es projective texture mapping

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture-mapping

I'm trying to map correctly a texture in a trapezoid using Projective Texture Mapping as explained in the [Cass's paper](https://developer.nvidia.com/system/files/akamai/gamedev/docs/projective_texture_mapping.pdf). I'm using opengl es 2.0 in android environment. I am new to opengl and I'm not sure that all of my assumptions I have done to adapt the Cass's suggest to my case are correct.
I tried in many ways to make this works but I didn't get it right. I can see the texture in the shape but not in the right way. Any tips? Thanks.

Camera setup:

```
// trapezoid space coordinates
    private float squareCoords[] = {
        -0.2f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   
         0.2f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; 

// Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// set the projection matrix 
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

// Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
```

My model matrix is an identity matrix.

I want my projector in the same position of the camera. So I suppose that the projection matrix has the same coordinates of the camera matrix.

Texture projection

```
float [] textureCoords=new float[16];

//I use this matrix to obtein the Object Linear Texgen (To)
float[] scaleBiasMatrix = new float[] { 
                0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f,
                0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        };

// calculate the To Matrix
// I'm not sure about this but I use mvpMatrix to multiply Pp*Vp*M because M is an identity, and Pp and Vp should be the same of mViewMatrix and mProjectionMatrix
            Matrix.multiplyMM(To, 0, scaleBiasMatrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0);

    for (int j=0;j<4;j++) {
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            if (i!=3) { 
                vSquare[i]=this.squareCoords[h]; //adding w coordinate to each vertex
                h++;
            }
            else
                vSquare[i]=1;

        }
        Matrix.multiplyMV(tSquare, 0, To, 0, vSquare , 0); //for each vertex
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            textureCoords[k]=tSquare[i]; //set the texture coordinates for each vertex
            k++;

        }
    }

// initialize texture byte buffer
    ByteBuffer mSquareTextureCoordinates = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoords.length * 4);
    mSquareTextureCoordinates.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer=mSquareTextureCoordinates.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(textureCoords);
    textureBuffer.position(0);
```

Vertex Shader

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 a_TexCoordinate; // Per-vertex texture coordinate information we will pass in.
varying vec4 v_TexCoordinate; // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
void main() {
        gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
        // Pass through the texture coordinate.
        v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;
}
```

Fragment shader

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;  // The input texture.
varying vec4 v_TexCoordinate; // Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.
void main() {
        gl_FragColor=texture2DProj(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the texture is in the shape but not the right way"? What your code does is simply projectiong the texture into the scene, completely filling the viewport. It is the same as if you would just normalize `gl_FragCoord.xy` to the [0,1] range. So what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Actually the texture is projected exactly into the shape. As I said the problem is that it doesn't apply correctly. What I was trying to achieve was correctly texturing a trapezoid through projection mapping. I finally found a different but effective solution here: http://www.bitlush.com/posts/arbitrary-quadrilaterals-in-opengl-es-2-0